# plsql: return match if every row is match, else show dismatch fields

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table TESTCOMPARE like this

`customer | order | date | history | number| .....`

`match    | match | match| mismatch| match | .....`

(it's a large table and headers won't change but values may change)

I want to return a single table like

`|overall|`

`|match|`
if every field in my table is match.

Or return a single table which only contains the mismatch fields. eg:

`|history|`

`|mismatch|`

How to do it in pl/sql? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some sample data and wanted result, and it will be much easier to understand.

Comment: @jarlh The first table is sample data and the next two are wanted result.

Comment: if there are two fields mismatching for a given row, do you want two rows to appear in your mismatched fields dataset, or do you want a single row with a delimited list?

Comment: @Boneist I want two rows in mismatched fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want but you need to list all the columns:

```
select tc.*
from testcompare tc
where 'mismatch' not in (customer, order, date, history, number, . . .);
```

Your second question can be accomplished in several ways.  The easiest conceptually is:

```
select 'customer' from testcompare where customer = 'mismatch' and rownum = 1
union all
select 'order' from testcompare where order = 'mismatch' and rownum = 1
union all
. . .
```

Comment: I can't list all the columns because there're too many.. Is it possible to do it by loop or sth?

Comment: You can set up dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).  But, you can just get the columns from `all_tab_cols`.  I would put them into a spreadsheet and generate the SQL there.  If you need to to work over time (such as in a stored procedure), then you would want the same logic as dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what output you're actually after, so here are different ways of getting output that may be of some use to you:

```
with testcompare as (select 1 id, 'match' col1, 'match' col2, 'match' col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 'match' col1, 'match' col2, 'mismatch' col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 'match' col1, 'mismatch' col2, 'mismatch' col3 from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 'mismatch' col1, 'mismatch' col2, 'match' col3 from dual)
select id,
       case when col1 = 'match'
                 and col2 = 'match'
                 and col3 = 'match'
                 then 'match'
            else 'mismatch'
       end overall,
       case when col1 = 'match'
                 and col2 = 'match'
                 and col3 = 'match'
                 then 'match'
            else rtrim(decode(col1, 'mismatch', 'col1,')||
                       decode(col2, 'mismatch', 'col2,')||
                       decode(col3, 'mismatch', 'col3'), ',')
       end overall_with_mismatched_cols
from   testcompare;

        ID OVERALL  OVERALL_WITH_MISMATCHED_COLS
---------- -------- ----------------------------
         1 match    match                       
         2 mismatch col3                        
         3 mismatch col2,col3                   
         4 mismatch col1,col2     

with testcompare as (select 1 id, 'match' col1, 'match' col2, 'match' col3 from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 'match' col1, 'match' col2, 'mismatch' col3 from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 'match' col1, 'mismatch' col2, 'mismatch' col3 from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 'mismatch' col1, 'mismatch' col2, 'match' col3 from dual)
select id,
       mismatch_col_name
from   testcompare
unpivot (col_val for mismatch_col_name in (col1, col2, col3))
where  col_val = 'mismatch';

        ID MISMATCH_COL_NAME
---------- -----------------
         2 COL3             
         3 COL2             
         3 COL3             
         4 COL1             
         4 COL2
```

As for your comment to Gordon's answer of "I can't list all the columns because there're too many" ... really? You "can't"? Or do you mean you don't want to? Most gui's have a table view that you can select all the columns and then it's just a matter of searching and replacing to add the other bits and bobs like commas, etc.

Or you could write a sql statement to generate the list of columns, which you can then amend as appropriate to fit into your query. Eg. taking the "overall" column from my first query above, I'd write a query to generate the when clause as something like:

```
select '                 and '||column_name||' = ''match''' col1
from   user_table_columns
where  table_name = 'TESTCOMPARE';
```